# Is there a way to print log only once at the time of starting of Spring Scheduler (ex: scheduler start)to avoid same logs being print again and again?

Tags: spring, scheduler

I want to log if my Spring scheduler started and up and running, I cant put the log inside my @Scheduled method, as it will keep on printing on every execution.
Is there any way to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very easy.

```
@Sl4j
public class MySchedulerClass {
     private boolean logDone = false;

     @Scheduled(...)
     public void executeScheduler() {
         if (!logDone) {
             log.info("About to start scheduled job for the first time");
             logDone = true;
          }
          // your business logic here
     }
```

Of course, if for whichever reason your application restarts during the time your scheduler is active, you will get this log entry again which in my view is a good thing. If you don't want this to happen, then you have to persist `logDone` somwhere external to the application such as a database.

We had an even more interesting requirement to show this only at the start of the job but every day. We resolved it with a chron scheduler resetting the `logDone` of the scheduler performing the task.

Comment: Thank you, I feel its kind if a hack we use, I was wondering if we have any out of the box method provided by sprig.